# How login with Facebook and Google without authentication in Laravel 5.1 using socialite version 2.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => 'id',
    'client_secret' =>
    'fgdfgsdfgrtt45453',
    'redirect' => 'http://example.com/callback',
],
```

In **route.php**

```
Route::get('/redirect', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@callback');
```

And I have add `Services/SocialFacebookAccountService.php` directory in **App**.

**SocialFacebookAccountService.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\SocialFacebookAccount;
use App\User;
use Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\User as ProviderUser;

class SocialFacebookAccountService {

    public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser) {
        $account = SocialFacebookAccount::whereProvider('facebook')
                ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
                ->first();
        echo 'Account info : ';

        if ($account) {
            return $account->user;
        } else {

            $account = new SocialFacebookAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'facebook'
            ]);

            $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();

            if (!$user) {

                $user = User::create([
                            'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                            'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                            'password' => md5(rand(1, 10000)),
                ]);
            }

            $account->user()->associate($user);
            $account->save();

            return $user;
        }
    }

}
```

Please help, How to get user info in callback.

Answer (score 0):

In your `callback` method:

```
   public function callback($provider=facebook)
   {
      if($user = $this->socialite->with($provider)->user()){
         dd($user); //user details
      }else{
         return 'something went wrong';
      }
   }
```